# Правописание артиклей к иностранным дворянским фамилиям

Tags: орфография, ономастика

Как пишутся артикли к иностранным дворянским фамилиям: с большой или с маленькой буквы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все артикли к иностранным фамилиями пишутся с маленькой буквы.
Примеры: *да Винчи, д'Эон, ван Рейн, фон Браун, Исмаил-бей, Саид-эфенди*.